# Getting stale data in Server Side Rendered Page on client side rendering using @apollo/react-hoc

Tags: reactjs, graphql, server-side-rendering, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a use case where i need to Server Side Render my component [React App], which uses apollo-client to call the API.
Apollo client, by default, uses `cache-first` fetch Policy in case of Server Side Rendering.
If I change the policy to `network-only`, the entire content that was received from the server, is re-rendered as soon as the component loads on client.

My problem is, once the page is returned from the server, using `cache-first` fetch policy, and the page gets re-rendered on the client due to some action performed by the user, the data is always fetched from the cache, but I need to get fresh data using network call instead of using stale data. How can i achieve that ?